# find specific names in unix

Tags: unix, sed, awk, grep

I want to print cities that fulfill 3 conditions: `capital`, `clean` and `big`.

**Input:**

```
London is a big city
London is a capital
London is a clean city
Ohio is a big city
Sydney is a big city
Sydney is a clean city
Canberra is a capital
Canberra is a big city
Canberra is a clean city
NewYork is a big city
NewYork is a clean city
```

**Output:**

```
London
Canberra
```

I need only those names which fulfill all the 3 conditions: capital, clean and big.

I tried to `cut` the first column in separate file then for each city do `grep name file|wc -l` and take only those which have count more than 3. How can this be done in Unix using `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried.

Comment: what have I tried is...

Cut the first column in separate file  

then for each city do
grep name file|wc -l

and take only those which have count more than 3

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  People will help you with problems with your code; people won't simply write the code for you.  Please edit what you've tried so far into the question.  Note that running `cut` on the first column throws away the information about which type of city it is.

Comment: Of the tools you list (`grep`, `sed`, `cut`, `awk`), I think `awk` is the tool of choice for this problem.  You need three separate lists of cities: those which are clean, those which are big, and those which are a capital city.  When you've read all the data, you can cycle through, say, all the big cities, and for each big city, check whether it appears in the list of capital cities and the list of clean cities, printing it if it does.

Comment: Or you can have one map of cities to a combination of their properties, as I showed in a perl demo (gnar. I won't be learning `awk`. I don't care how useful it is. I know enough crazy archaic (shell) script language (dialects))

Comment: London is clean and Canberra big? OMG! Where have you been, dear ?

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun.

The shell hacker's solution:

```
sort -u input.txt | cut -d' ' -f1 | uniq -dc | egrep '^\s+3\s'
```

The perl hacker's solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use constant {
    CAPITAL => 1,
    CLEAN   => 2,
    BIG     => 4,
};
my %table;

while(<>)
{
    print STDERR "Unparsed: $_" unless m/^(\w+)\s+is a\s+((big city)|(clean city)|(capital))\s*$/gio;

    $table{$1} |= defined($3) * BIG +
                  defined($4) * CLEAN +
                  defined($5) * CAPITAL;
}

while (my ($k,$v) = each %table)
{
    print "$k\n" if (CAPITAL+CLEAN+BIG) == $v;
}
```